# render_to_string() got multiple values for argument 'context_instance'

Tags: django, django-views

I am trying to pass the following argument to a render to response syntax in django but i keep getting the following error:

> render_to_string() got multiple values for argument 'context_instance'

Tried different solutions but still not getting it right. Any help?

views.py:

```
@login_required

def articles(request, everyone=True):

    events = post.objects.filter()
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        my_events = events.filter(user=request.user) 
        events = events.exclude(user=request.user)
        following = request.user.following_set.all().values_list('to_user', 
            flat=True)
    else:
        my_events = post.objects.none()
        following = None
    if not everyone:
        events = events.filter(user__in=following)

        args = {}
        args.update(csrf(request))
        args ['posts'] = post.objects.filter(user = request.user)
        args ['full_name'] = User.objects.get(username = request.user.username)
        args ['form'] = PostForm()
        args ['forms'] = CommentForm()
        args ['profile_picture'] = request.user.profile.profile_picture

        context = {
        'events': events,
        'my_events': my_events,
        'following': following,
    }


    return render_to_response('articles.html', args, context,
        context_instance = RequestContext(request))
```

Is there anything am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the render_to_string from the django source django.template.engine :

```
def render_to_string(self, template_name, dictionary=None, context_instance=None,
                         dirs=_dirs_undefined):
```

It gets called with `(*args,**kwargs)` passed from `render_to_response()` It is clear that your `context` argument conflicts with keyword argument assigned by you which is `context_instance`. You should only send one of those. Maybe you should put the data from `context` inside your `args` dictionary?

By the way you can look at the docs here:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#the-render-to-string-shortcut
and here:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#render-to-response

to see the list of arguments each of this functions accepts.

Comment: thank you i put in the data in the context in the args dictinary and it worked thanks a lot saved a life